# Kivy- Building an APK

Tags: python, permissions, apk, kivy

## Initial problem

I wrote an app in python using kivy libraries, and have reached the stage where i want to buid an APK to run on my android device. As advised on the kivy website I run the following:

```
buildozer android debug
```

But get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.15-dev', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 957, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 163, in prepare_for_build
    self.check_garden_requirements()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 477, in check_garden_requirements
    self.state['cache.gardenlibs'] = garden_requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/jsonstore.py", line 33, in __setitem__
    self.sync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.15_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/jsonstore.py", line 54, in sync
    with io.open(self.filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/linuxlite/abc/.buildozer/state.db'
```

I can see that this is a permissions issue, and I would be grateful if someone can give some advice on fixing it.

---

## Edit

After fixing the permissions issue I now get the following:

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name myapp --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/linuxlite/abc/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo buildozer android debug`?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply ... ive just tried it .. now this erroe pops up ..

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name myapp --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/linuxlite/abc/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug

Comment: @user3532371 Im sure there is more to the error than that ..

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/2092ceh.jpg

Comment: maybe try `sudo su` then just run `buildozer android debug` ... I dunno I just used the VirtualBox that kivy provides and it was very very easy ... (although to be fair I never messed with buildozer at all ...)

Comment: Are you talking about the image that they are providing in the download page 
? ( ~ 900 mb )

Comment: Please don't run buildozer as root, it doesn't need it. I suggest deleting all the buildozer directories (or carefully repermissioning them to your own user) and running it again. If it fails, paste the whole error log here or in a pastebin - not an image, the text.

Comment: @inclement hey can you please tell me how do i give permission to buildozer's dirs to my own user

Comment: It's easiest to just delete them all and run buildozer again.

Comment: You should delete ~/.buildozer and also any .buildozer dirs inside of your project. You may need to use sudo to delete them due to the previous bad advice of using sudo to run buildozer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your initial question is to use the `chown` command like this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:`groups | awk '{print $1}'` ~/.buildozer .
```

That will reset the permissions for both your global buildozer config, and your project, to your own user and group. From this point please don't use `sudo` with buildozer. In fact consider the use of `sudo` for anything other than installation to be a ***BAD THING***.

As for your new issue, I'm not sure what is going on here - I myself have come across the same issue, which is where I found your question. If I get to the bottom of it I shall update this answer.